# List Windows network connections/profiles in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Can someone point me to a class to list the current network profiles installed on a Windows machine (XP,Vista,7,8,8.1) in C#?

I basically want a list of the following along with their connection status:

[image: Windows network connections]

I have had a look at the `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` function but that obviously just returns the physical adapters, what I am looking for is the network profiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the [Network List Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which enables applications to retrieve the list of available network connections. [The Windows API Code Pack for .Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/06/12/windows-api-code-pack-for-microsoft-net-framework.aspx) wraps this API so that it can be used easily by managed applications. Add the NuGet package

> Windows API Code Pack - Core

Call the following function to list the network profiles:

```
public void ListNetworkProfiles()
{
    NetworkCollection nCollection = NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.All);
    foreach (Network net in nCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + net.Name + " Status: " + (net.IsConnected ? "Connected" : "Not Connected"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. I assume there must be some sort of Win32 call available to handle also but this works great!